# What does "had in charge" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I came across the following phrase, and I would like to know what is the meaning of **"had in charge"** in this context.

"The order of Saint Lazar patronized the leprotics, the order of Saint loan **had in charge** Jerusalem patients in 1099".

I looked for "had in charge in" on google and I didn't find this idiom but I found "charge in" in meaning of "responsible for".

Comment: The phrase is "had in charge", not "had in charge in". Have you looked up the word "charge" in a dictionary?

Comment: @DavidC: It might be a bit formal / Victorian, but *The schoolmistress had in charge several unruly children [in recent years, whatever]* is a tolerable resequencing of *The schoolmistress had several unruly children in [her] charge*.

Comment: We find the prepositional complement before and after the direct object. Normally it comes after the direct object:  *They **had** several small children **in tow*** but if the direct object is modified by a clause, the complement can come before it: *They **had in tow** several small children who were licking large lollipops and gazing around with bewildered expressions.*

Comment: Source please!  If you didn't write this yourself, could you please link to the source.

Answer (score 1):

It's "abnormal" phrasing (not surprising, since it seems to be translated from [a Russian original](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22order+of+Saint+Lazar+patronized%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&oq=%22order+of+Saint+Lazar+patronized%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.2930j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)).

The comma doesn't help. Most writers would either start a new sentence there or introduce a suitable conjunction such as ***while***. Whatever - just considering the second statement...

> *The order of Saint loan **had in charge** Jerusalem patients in 1099*

...would more naturally be expressed as...

> *The order of Saint loan had Jerusalem patients in [their] charge in 1099*

...or with more wholesale rephrasing...

> *In 1099, the order of Saint loan looked after patients from Jerusalem*

Comment: It has been a common phrase since the 17th c.  It isn't colloquial but it's certainly not "abnormal" and the Russian original had nothing to do with it.

Comment: Perhaps this is yet another matter of opinion. I find it hard to believe any native speaker would *ever* have written OP's exact text if it hadn't arisen in the context of a translation. I don't actually know precisely how to parse it anyway. Does ***in 1099*** apply to just the "Jerusalem patients", or the leprotics as well? Who has ever called lepers ***leprotics**?* Why use a comma instead of a period or a meaningful conjunction? That's all quite apart from the quirky sequence ***to have in charge [patients]*** (rather than *have **them** in charge* or *be in charge **of them***).